# Java average returns me infinity

Tags: java, android, arrays

my program use a Write to save a double(ratingbar.rating) and a read to put the saved file inside a array. Then, with the array, I do an average of the numbers inside the array. In the read code, when I had getResources("raw.file") was working fine and the return was correct, but now I need to write the numbers and for that I can't use the res folder, so now I'm using the Internal Storage and my average returns me INFINITY. The average is called in a button OnClickListener. 
I'll post the code:

Write

```
private void writeMyArray(double rate){
    //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("arraymedia.txt", true)));
    //.println(rate);
    double ratex2 = rate * 2;
    int erate = (int)ratex2;
        try{
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myarray.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
            outputStreamWriter.append(Integer.toString(erate));
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Read

```
private void readMyArray(ArrayList<Double>array){
    String ret = "";
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("myarray.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int enc = 0;
            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                array.add(enc, Double.parseDouble(receiveString));
                ++enc;
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Average

```
private double media(ArrayList<Double>array)
{
    double total = 0;
    double media;
    int a = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
    {
        total = total + array.get(i);
        a=i;
    }
    media = total / a;
    return media;
}
```

Button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            rating = ratingbar.getRating();

           writeMyArray(rating);
            readMyArray(arraydays);
            button.setText(getText(R.string.obrigado) + "!" + media(arraydays));
            //button.setText(getText(R.string.obrigado)+"!");
            ratingbar.setEnabled(false);
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: How many items should there be in the list? 'cause perhaps the focus of the answers are second to the reading problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Division amounts to infinity in java if your denominator is 0.0 (0 in float or double). Please check before dividing.

Comment: media = total / a; value of a is 0 in this statement. that's why infinity.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop there is a mistake, dont use `a=i`, that cause (if only one element) `a=0` with result of infinity. use `i+1` instead to add `1` in each iteration

```
int i = 0;
for (i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
{
    total = total + array.get(i);
    // a=i;  // wrong
}
media = total / (i + 1);
return media;
```

Comment: Why? a will be array.size() -1 because that's the last value of i that comes in the for loop

Comment: Problem is that the initial value of a is important here, saver is 'a = array.size()'

Comment: agree with that.... also using `i+1` at the end of the loop will save you one variable

Comment: there is now... just open the scope... xDDDD

Comment: then the rest of the code... If you initialize 'i' before the for loop, you don't need a declaring variable... Then proceed with the rest

Answer (score 0):

```
private double media(ArrayList<Double>array){
    double total = 0;
    double media;
    int a = array.size(); // set to size of array, instead of setting to i
    for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
        total = total + array.get(i);
    }
    if(a==0) //if a == 0 // divide by 0 -> infinity
        media = 0;
    else
        media = total / a;
    return media;
}
```